# Second monitor emulator as an application window in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors

Using Windows 10 / 64 Pro version 1809.
I recently purchased a WQHD monitor and have a need for the following use case:

1. I teach online courses for which I need to be able to present and switch between PowerPoint, Web browser, and an IDE.
2. The presentation resolution is 1280x720, which I would like to fit in a window on my desktop and use the rest for my notes and scripts.
3. My screen sharing utility allows for 'lock on application' instead of full screen or pre-configured area, and I would like to lock it on this 'virtual monitor' window so I don't have to switch sharing between the apps as it takes too long and is error prone.

I checked this forum and others and all I could find are solutions that enable either:

1. Multiple desktops, but each covers the entire screen. 
   The built-in windows multiple desktops feature does it nicely.
2. Allow for spitting the main monitor screen to multiple smaller virtual monitors, but each has to be a rectangle which wasted a huge amount of my screen's area, and it is not movable.
3. Allow for 'fake' virtual monitors that can only be seen with an RDP, but that sounds way too convoluted for what I need.

What I really need is a utility that will emulate a second monitor, and show it in a movable, re-sizable application window that I can run all the presented utilities, and allow locking to my screen sharing utility.

Any idea if such a thing exists?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well one solution would be to use a Virtual Machine!(you can set it up in minutes), like VMware or Oracle Virtual Box and then you can run your screen sharing utility from the virtual machine, and use the rest of the area for your notes and scripts.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts @Elmo. I thought about a VM, but it sounds like a huge overkill for such a simple requirement, I'll have to maintain another OS with everything installed on it. would be easier with the 'fake' virtual monitor IMHO.